# Increasing a variable by either .5 or 1, depending on current value

Tags: python, renpy

I'm trying to make a manual increase of a value (via a button), and increase to the nearest whole number, before continuing to increase by one for each click.

So, if the variable is
`var = 1` increase by 1 to 2, but if `var = 1.5` increase to 2

This is done in Ren'py, but I don't care about that, as long as the solution is in Python code.

Currently, the increase code I have is this:
`SetVariable(stats[1]+"_dom",getattr(store,stats[1]+"_dom")+1)` (Ren'py specific)

I'm sure there is a simple way of doing this in Python, but I'm not 100% sure what to search for.

Comment: Add 1, then round down. (i.e. call `int()` or `math.floor()`)

Comment: Thanks, this worked wonders (the math.floor())

Comment: @JohnGordon would you mind making this into an answer, and I will accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 1, then round down. (`int()` or `math.floor()`)

Answer (score 1):

You could just do `variable = int(variable + 1)`

Comment: Neither of those did what I wanted, probably due to Renpy